# boolean algebra simplyfing

Tags: linear-algebra, boolean-algebra

I need to solve these expressions with boolean algebra:

$$Z = a'bc+ab'c+abc'+abc\mbox{ AND }Z = a'(b+db'c')+a'b'(d'c'+c)$$

Every advice is more then welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to expand both expressions to their respective [CDNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form)s (with respect to $a,b,c$ and $d$), and see if any of the canonical conjunctions overlap. In your case, these two canonical conjunctions are part of both CDNFs: $a'bcd'$ and $a'bcd$. 
 So, the solution is: $a'bcd' \vee a'bcd = a'bc$.